# Nestling Posts Under Page & Justify Text

Tags: posts, pages

I've recently come returned to blogging. I'm currently using Wordpress and I have a few personal initiatives. For the life of me I can't figure out how to have some posts go in one of the initiatives, and other posts go in the second initiative. Right now, everything just gets posted on my Home page.

Also, it seems like the new 'block' feature has removed the 'text justify'. Is there any way to return this?

Can any of you kind souls help me out?

Comment: You can use Categories to group posts. However, many themes will show all Posts from any Category on the homepage. You can look for another theme that doesn't do this, or you can set a Page as a static homepage, so that on your homepage you just see whatever content you put in that Page - i.e. links to the different Categories.

Comment: The blocks, eg paragraphs can be justified. You just have to click on the text and a toolbar appears above the block - one button should be the justification.